# error 500 : ApiError when trying to upload file into GCS using GAE Flexible

Tags: node.js, typescript, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to do an API deployed with Google App Engine flexible that uploads files into Google Storage. When I run the API with `localhost` it works pretty well. But with the deployed application, I get this error:

```
ApiError: Error during request.
at Object.parseHttpRespBody (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/src/util.js:187:32)
at Object.handleResp (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/src/util.js:131:18)
```

I granted the storage admin permission to the service account but same error as well.

```
export function toStorage(request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) {
  const storage = Storage({
    projectId: process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT
  })
  // A bucket is a container for objects (files).
  const bucket = storage.bucket(process.env.OUTPUT)
  console.log(process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT)
  console.log(process.env.OUTPUT)
  if (!request.file) {
    response.status(400).send('No file uploaded.')
    return
  }

  // Create a new blob in the bucket and upload the file data.
  const blob = bucket.file(request.file.originalname)
  const blobStream = blob.createWriteStream({
    resumable: false
  })

  blobStream.on('error', (err: Error) => {
    next(err)
  })

  blobStream.on('finish', () => {
    // The public URL can be used to directly access the file via HTTP.
    const publicUrl = format(`https://storage.googleapis.com/${bucket.name}/${blob.name}`)
    sendResponse(response, publicUrl)
  })

  blobStream.end(request.file.buffer)

}
```

Thanks in advance to the support help.

Comment: at this time , i still not found any solution